# What does "authResponse" param do inside FB.init()?

Tags: facebook

[`FB.init()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) docs state that you can pass some mysterious `authResponse` param to it which is `Object also retrievable by getAuthResponse`. What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Though FB's documentation is sparse in this matter, [a blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/) explains what's happening. Once oauth is enabled in the FB.init, the FB.login will respond with a response object that contains the authResponse, which can apparently stored by the application and installed when you the FB.init in the succeeding application-accesses.

Specifically, I am quoting from the [same post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/) :

> As with sessions, an authorization record can be installed when
>   FB.init is called by including an authResponse parameter and attaching
>   it to a valid authorization response for the logged in user. Whereas
>   many developers would store sessions in a database, you might now
>   store authorization responses instead.